# local site redirecting to https and getting ssl error- nginx

Tags: http, nginx, ssl, https

I am not a backend server guy, mostly work the front end(design and Javascript work). So pardon my beginner questions/terminology. But I could really use some help! Due to covid I am working remote and this is just NOT my expertise.

I have 6 sites I work on locally via a local environment (Nginx, virtual box). Recently, out of nowhere 1 of the sites has started redirecting to an HTTPS version and it will NOT load on any browser due to "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR", so I can not work on that site as of now. All the other sites, that live in the same environment, load fine and are not secure versions.

I have looked at their config files and they are all the same. I don't understand how 1 site is NOW getting redirected to an HTTPS version, I never get into the Ngnix system to change things. And unless I'm missing something it's my local env so nothing could be introduced from the outside.

**Questions:** Can I just redirect it back to the HTTP version??? OR can I add some certificate to fix my "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" error?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated and the gods will shine upon you.